# Последовательность вычислений на Си

Tags: c

Массив `char m[]` надо превратить в строку, заменив последний элемент нулём. Количество элементов в массиве `i`. Будет ли правильно написать

```
m[--i]=0;
```

или `i` будет уменьшено уже после присвоения и произойдёт выход за границы массива?
Как написать правильно?

Comment: Лучше такие конструкции не употреблять.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
m[--i]=0;
```

Сначала будет выполнен декремент, а потом присваивание, как если бы код был

```
--i;
m[i]=0;
```

И наоборот:

```
m[i--]=0;
```

Сначала будет выполнено присваивание, а потом декремент, как если бы код был

```
m[i]=0;
i--;
```

Comment: Если вдруг автор читает комментарии, добавлю что лучше использовать более развернутые варианты(второй и четвертый). А то так и до  `i = i++ + ++i;` недалеко.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь нет никакого "до" и "после" и рассуждать о поведении этого кода в таких терминах - грубая ошибка. Никакого "декремент выполнится до" и "присваивание выполнится после" тут гарантировать нельзя. Но это и не нужно.

Все, что вам нужно знать в данном случае - это то, что индексом массива у вас является результат выражения `--i`. *По определению*, результатом выражения `--i` является исходное значение `i` уменьшенное на 1. То есть доступ к элементу массива у вас эквивалентен `m[<исходное значение i> - 1]` и никакого выхода за пределы массива здесь не будет.

Порядок вычисления тут никакой роли не играет и в какой момент произойдет изменение значения самого `i` (до или после) вас интересовать не должно. В языке С это не оговаривается.